# Allowing certain XHTML tags in an XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm designing an XML Schema for my website. One of the elements in the schema is called "comments", which is supposed to contain comments posted from users. I wan't to allow certain xhtml tags to be used: *b*, *i*, and *u* for styling. So far what I've done is to import the XHTML namespace, and then declare a complexType for my comments element:

```
<import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        schemaLocation="xhtml1-transitional.xsd" />

....

<element name="comments">
    <complexType mixed="true">
        <any minOccurs="0">
            <element ref="xhtml:u"/>
            <element ref="xhtml:b"/>
            <element ref="xhtml:i"/>
        </any>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

But this doesn't seem to work! At least the XML Schema won't validate via the IBM XML Schema Quality Checker. The xhtml1-transitional.xsd file is in the same folder as the XML Schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a `<[CDATA[ ... ]]>` section for the comments. I think you validate the tags in your application code, so you don't have to enforce the validation in the XSD again.

#### Edit:

Since you want an XSD solution only, I think the simplest way would be to define the comments tag as a string and escape the html special chars:

```
<xsd:element name="comments" type="xsd:string" />
```

I don't think, that it would be a good way to go to include the actual tags as XML in the schema, since it is just arbitrary content (what's with valid HTML, which is invalid XML? For example `<p>` without `</p>` is valid HTML, but invalid in XML).

The XML special characters to escape

```
" & ' < >
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something that's compatible with XML Schema, not DTD

Comment: I adjusted the answer. I don't think that it would be a good way to include the tags in the comment as actual XML, but rather as escaped arbitrary content.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error; <any/> can't have content. You may have to use instead (most likely) a repeating choice.