# XSLT: keep elements of some namesapces

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, schema

In my XML database I want an element named "commentary" to contain three things:

1. Plain text.
2. Some xhtml tags
3. Some TEI tags (TEI=text encoding initiave)

Example:

```
<commentary>
<TEI:persName>King Henry iv</TEI:persName> was an <xhtml:b>important</xhtml:b> person.
</commentary>
```

First of all: How can I declare this in my XML Schema? (Sorry, I found this thread [Allowing certain XHTML tags in an XML Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375837/allowing-certain-xhtml-tags-in-an-xml-schema) but it didn't help me.)

Then (and I think thats more complicated) I want my xslt (output:html) to do the following:

Put all the content of "commentary" into a "p" element, just take all xhtml tags, remove their prefixe and put them into the "p"; remove all TEI-tags but keep their content.

So, expected result would be:

```
<p>
King Henry iv was an <b>important</b> person.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the XSLT that will work for the slightly altered xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:TEI="urn:tei" 
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl xhtml TEI"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="commentary">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </p>
    </xsl:template>

  <!-- remove namepace, keep name -->
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- surpress nodes in a namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="TEI:*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns:TEI="urn:tei" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <commentary>
    <TEI:persName>King Henry iv</TEI:persName> was an <xhtml:b>important</xhtml:b> person.
  </commentary>
</root>
```

This is the schema that VS2010 generated for me based on the above xml

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:TEI="urn:tei" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="urn:tei" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="commentary">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="TEI:persName" />
              <xs:element ref="xhtml:b" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

TEI schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="urn:tei" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:tei" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="persName" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!

After a few minutes of testing I found out some problems which I was able to solve.

The XSLT didn't work for nested attributes. I solved that by simply replacing

```
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

Attributes were not processed. I added a for-each-loop for attributes:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./@*">
<xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The code works fine now for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xhtml and tei.xsl"?>
<root xmlns:tei="urn:tei" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <commentary>
      <tei:persName>
         <xhtml:b>
            <xhtml:a href="http://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Henry_IV_of_England">
               <xhtml:span style="font-size:20pt">King Henry iv</xhtml:span>
            </xhtml:a>
         </xhtml:b>
      </tei:persName>
      was an
      <xhtml:b>important</xhtml:b>
      person.
   </commentary>
</root>
```